# erc20 solidity initial supply

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a question about deploying an ERC20-Standard Token, 
the constructor public says: initialSupply = 100 000 000 *10** uint256(decimals);
totalSupply_ = initialSupply;
How much coin is the total supply then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you know the value of `decimals` it is quite simple, just a mathematical operation. Also `**` is exponentiation in solidity.

Comment: so if i have 18 decimals my Supply is 100 000 000 Tokens, am I right?

Comment: You can test that with a very simple contract on remix.

Comment: Sorry if it was a little unclear but if you also take into account your decimals and divide by `10^18` your amounts the yes your initial supply would be `100 000 000`.

Answer (score 3):

It entirely depends on your choice. i am generally input 18 in decimal, then if i want to supply 1billion coins, i should input 1000000000000000000000000000 in total supply. it's my contract address that supply 1billion coins. i hope it is helpful to you. https://etherscan.io/address/0xc1987fbb2a109d3eae6a648ce03b66f3b3b30795#code